# Finding the permutations satisfying $\pi = \pi^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

I have the permutation $\pi $, that satisfies $\pi = \pi^{-1} $. Then $\pi $ is probably an indentical permutation. Is it all, or are there another permutations that satisfy my task?

Comment: How about transpositions?

Comment: Or any product of disjoint transpositions.

Comment: I am not sure how do you mean it.

Comment: Do you know what a transposition is?

Comment: Are you familiar with cycle notation? What carmichael561 was saying was that a cycle like $(1 2)$ satisfies your equation. What I added was that a product of two cycles $(1 2)(3 4)$ also satsifies $\pi = \pi ^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Write $\pi$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any product of disjoint 2-cycles will have this property.